# C pointer shenanigans

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to implement a Queue in C (using a Linked List) to store pointers to data.  The en-queuing seems to be working fine, but some trouble with pointers upon de-queuing.

In my main():

```
void* data = malloc(sizeof(int));
dequeue(&Q, data);
printf("(%d) %d\n", k, *(int*)data);
```

dequeue():

```
int dequeue(struct queue *q, void *value)
{
    struct queue_node *tmp;

    if (!q->first) {
        value = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    value = q->first->data;
    tmp = q->first;
    if (q->first == q->last)
        q->first = q->last = NULL;
    else
        q->first = q->first->next;

    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Based on my debugging, it seems that the value of the *data pointer in the main() for loop doesn't retain the value that it's set to in dequeue().  What am I missing?

Edit:

```
struct queue_node
{
    struct queue_node *next;    
    void* data;
};

struct queue
{
    struct queue_node *first;
    struct queue_node *last;
};
```

Comment: Care to share your definition of the `queue` and `queue_node` structures, or is the guessing game part of the question? _Update_: thanks!

Comment: Also, why do you `free(tmp)`? Can you guarantee that that is a valid pointer to malloc()ed memory?

Comment: As in the answer below, you're not assigning the result to the right thing. You want to return a `void*`, so your argument should be a `void** pp`, and you assign `*pp = q->first->data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queue_node`'s `data` holds a pointer to some value (here it is an `int`, but it may not be true always, otherwise you'd use an `int` instead...)

Since this value was allocated with `malloc` (and is not a local variable) you need to also free it at some point.

So, change the function's signature to accept a `void**`, don't allocate space for an `int` in `main()` but call `dequeue` with `&data` as a parameter, where `void * data = 0`. Don't forget to `free` data when done.
In `dequeue`, set `*value = q->first->data`.

Comment: @Alexei: don't forget to test the answer and then accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the value of the "value" variable, which is a pointer local to the function.

If you want to set the value to which it points, use:

```
*value = 0;
```

and:

```
*value = q->first->data;
```

**Edit** (after question edit): Since queue_node.data is itself a pointer, it makes more sense to pass a void**, as @Andrei notes above.

Comment: @Andrei, this was posted before the edit showing the definition of queue_node. Based on the casts, I was guessing that the 'data' member was an int.

Comment: The system doesn't let me remove the downvote if you don't edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is a (void *) and you want the (int) value pointed to by data, you'll have to replace

`value = q->first->data;`

with

`*(int *)value = *(int *)q->first->data;`

in the function deque();

Comment: But in the dequeue() function, you don't know the data type that it's pointing to

Comment: Now that you updated the question, @Andrei has the right answer.